# Minimal size of a network buffer

Tags: tcp, network-programming, operating-system, udp, buffer

I'm a student and I'm taking right now an Operating Systems course. I've stumbled upon a strange answer for a question while learning for exam and I couldn't find an explanation for it.

**Question:** Suppose we have an Operating System which runs on low physical memory. Thus the designers decided to make the buffer (that handles all the work that is connected to the network) as small as possible. What can be the smallest size of the buffer?

**Answer:** Can't be implemented with one byte only, but can be implemented with 2 bytes size.

**My thoughts:** It has 4 answers, one of them is "3 bytes or more" so I thought that it's the right answer because in order to establish a connection you need at list to be able to send a header of tcp/udp or similar package that contains all the connection info, so I have no idea why it's the right answer (according to the reference). Maybe some degenerate case?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Seems like a strange answer, and strange question too. Is there any more context? An IP header is 20 bytes.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the whole question.. I thought I'm missing something.. But I guess I'll have to ask the person who wrote this question.

Comment: I guess there's an argument that a one byte buffer doesn't buy you anything, but a two byte buffer does, as it cuts the writes to the next stage in half. But buffers have to be administrated: somebody has to know their address and length, which is much more than two bytes, so in practice you would want to amortize that overhead over a much larger buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The buffer has to be at least as large as the packet size on the network. That will depend upon the type of hardware interface. I know of no network system, even going back to the days of dialup, that used anything close to 2 bytes.

Maybe, in theory, you could have a network system that used 2-byte packets. The same logic would allow you to use 1-byte packets (transmitting fractions of a byte in a packets).

Sometimes I wonder about the questions CS professors come up with. I guess that's why:

1. Those who can do, do;
2. Those who can't do, teach;
3. Those who can't do and can't teach, teach PE.

Comment: 'Fractions of a byte'?

Comment: encode 4 bits of data and have 4 bits of overhead for a 1-byte package. use two packets to transmit one byte.

Comment: Sometimes I guess your comment about CS professors may be right, but in my case not so much, the one who has taught me OS this semester is brilliant, he can do and even more than you can imagine. He is one of the developers behind the Zcash crypto-currency that may very well change the well known bitcoin one day. But I agree they sometimes ask not clear and confusing questions.